# Error with ggplot2 after installing new R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanted to install a new version of R.
I downloaded R-3.1.0.pkg and installed it.
I mved my packages from `~/Library/R/3.0` to `~/Library/R/3.1`

the new R starts, but when I try to load some packages, I get an error.
This seems to be due to ggplot2.  As I can load any package that doesn't depend on ggplot2.
I just reinstalled ggplot2 using `install.packges()`, but still no luck.  R just crashes when I try to load the library.

I performed `update.packages()`. Is this related to how I migrated my packages?

Also, I seem to have packages in multiple places.  Although I think RStudio seems to install all of them in the `~/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/library`

thanks

```
> library(Hmisc)
Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: lattice
Loading required package: survival
Loading required package: Formula
Loading required package: ggplot2

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 5: loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))
 6: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 8: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 9: tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) {    call <- conditionCall(e)    if (!is.null(call)) {        if (identical(call[[1L]], quote(doTryCatch)))             call <- sys.call(-4L)        dcall <- deparse(call)[1L]        prefix <- paste("Error in", dcall, ": ")        LONG <- 75L        msg <- conditionMessage(e)        sm <- strsplit(msg, "\n")[[1L]]        w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "w") + nchar(sm[1L], type = "w")        if (is.na(w))             w <- 14L + nchar(dcall, type = "b") + nchar(sm[1L],                 type = "b")        if (w > LONG)             prefix <- paste0(prefix, "\n  ")    }    else prefix <- "Error : "    msg <- paste0(prefix, conditionMessage(e), "\n")    .Internal(seterrmessage(msg[1L]))    if (!silent && identical(getOption("show.error.messages"),         TRUE)) {        cat(msg, file = stderr())        .Internal(printDeferredWarnings())    }    invisible(structure(msg, class = "try-error", condition = e))})
10: try({    ns <- loadNamespace(package, c(which.lib.loc, lib.loc))    env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps)})
11: library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc)
12: .getRequiredPackages2(pkgInfo, quietly = quietly)
13: library(Hmisc
```

Comment: You must do `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

Comment: Current R version is 3.2.1.

Comment: thank you , I know, I just go into trouble before when a few of the packages I depended on didn't work with the current R version.

Comment: Not `update.packages()`, but `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`. By default, `checkBuilt` is set to `FALSE`.

Comment: thanks, this checkBuilt worked. but even after reading the help page I'm not exactly sure what this did

Comment: It compares the version of R you have and the version of R the packages were built against.